# Automatic printing of files written in specific directory

Tags: ubuntu, printing, daemon

I have a legacy application that for printing purposes, sends its output to a file in different directories. What's written into directory X is printed in printer X; what's written into directory Y is printed in printer Y; and what's written into directory Z is converted into a PDF, and the PDF handler program is launched.

This setup works fine in Windows.

I'd like to replicate it in Ubuntu Linux. So I'd like a daemon that would monitor a directory, so that it would send whatever is written into that directory to a specific printer queue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[incron](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=about&lang=en), it's in Ubuntu's universe repository

Comment: incron did the trick! BTW, I found this site http://linux.die.net/man/8/incrond to have clearer documentation than http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=about&lang=en